# Unable to access site remotely

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

we have IIS 7.5 on server machine.

All websites can be access locally (80 and 8081 port as well)

However, only port 80 website can be accessed remotely. But the website on 8081 cannot be accessed remotely.

What is wrong?

Comment: Firewall turned on? Add inbound rule for TCP on port 8081.

Comment: yes, but http are not blocked. I checked this in firewall->exceptions..

Comment: What do you mean by "http"? Default port for is 80.

Comment: under firewall.cpl -> allow an app/feature through firewall -> http is marked, so is that still issue?\

Comment: Uder firewall.cpl -> Advanced settings -> Inbound rules -> Add new rule for port 8081, TCP (note: translation from non-english Windows version so not sure if names are exact)

Comment: thats perfect.. Illt ry this..

Comment: Can you write this in answer below so I can mark you

Comment: Answer added, happy to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you have firewall turned on for non standard ports (even if HTTP protocol is used and HTTP is enabled in firewall app/feature settings because it defaults to port 80).

To enable remote port 8018 access: under *firewall.cpl* -> *Advanced settings* -> *Inbound rules* add new rule for port 8081, TCP